# React+Firebase: Store clicked btns with useState

Tags: reactjs, use-state

Hi I am a newbie to React and have been creating a quiz app with React and Firebase.

I was trying to implement disabled btns after users clicked them. I could do so by adding a className called "disableClick". But the problem was that it disables btn that have the same index. For example, if I click a btn with index 1 on a question, index-1-btns in other questions get disabled.
Then I started using useState hook to store all clicked btns with a key of quizIndex.
it visually is below.

```js
  /*
  Ideally
  {
    quizIndex: [
      "answer1", "answer2"
    ], 
    quizIndex : [
      "buiohlnk"
    ]
  }
  */
```

But, I haven't still understood useState() perfectly so I have got bunch of errors in a handleJuege function.
Thanks for your time in advance.

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { doc, collection, onSnapshot } from 'firebase/firestore';

import db from '../firebaseConfig';
import { click } from '@testing-library/user-event/dist/click';

const Quiz = () => {
  const [quizzes, setQuizzes] = useState([]);
  const [disableClick, setDisableClick] = useState('ableClick');
  const [clickedAnswers, setClickedAnswers] = useState(new Map());
  /*
  Ideally
  {
    quizIndex: [
      "answer1", "answer2"
    ], 
    quizIndex : [
      "buiohlnk"
    ]
  }
  */
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const collectionRef = collection(db, 'quizzes');

    const unsub = onSnapshot(
      collectionRef,
      {
        next: (snapshot) => {
          setQuizzes(
            snapshot.docs.map(
              doc => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })
            )
          );
        },
        error: (err) => {
          // don't forget error handling! e.g. update component with an error message
          console.error("quizes listener failed: ", err);
        }
      }
    );
    return unsub;
    // const unsub = onSnapshot(collectionRef, snapshot => {
    //   setQuizzes(snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
    // });
    // return unsub;
    // getData(): run once
    // onSnapshot(): listen for realtime updates
  }, []);

  const handleJudge = (a, quiz, answerIndex, quizIndex) => {
    const correctAnswer = quiz.answers[quiz.correctAnswer];
    console.log(`a => ${a}, correctAnswer => ${correctAnswer}, answerIndex => ${answerIndex}, quizIndex => ${quizIndex}`);


    setClickedAnswers({...clickedAnswers, quizIndex: a});
    console.log(`clickedAnswers => ${clickedAnswers}`)

    // if (clickedAnswers.size === 0) {
    //   clickedAnswers.set(quizIndex, [a]);
    // } else {
    //   clickedAnswers.set(quizIndex, [clickedAnswers.get(quizIndex)]);
    // }
    // console.log(clickedAnswers, clickedAnswers.get(quizIndex)); 

    if (correctAnswer === a) {
      alert('Awesome!! The correct answer is ' + a);
      const eachQuizClickedAnswers = new Map();
      eachQuizClickedAnswers.set(quizIndex, [a])
      console.log(`each => ${eachQuizClickedAnswers.get(quizIndex)}`)
      setDisableClick('disableClick');
    } else {
      // setClickedAnswers([...clickedAnswers, answerIndex])
      setDisableClick('disableClick');
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className='quizContainer'>
      {quizzes.map((quiz, quizIndex) => (
        <div key={quiz.id} className='quiz'>
          <div className='quizQContainer'>
            <p className='quizQText'>{quiz.question}</p>
          </div>
          <ul className='answersContainer'>
            {quiz.answers.map((a, answerIndex) => (
              <li
                key={a}
                onClick={() => {
                  handleJudge(a, quiz, answerIndex, quizIndex);
                }}
                // className={clickedAnswers.get(answerIndex) ? disableClick : ""}
              >
                <a disabled={true} href='#'>
                  {a}
                </a>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
          <div className='quizFooter'>
            <div className='likesDislikesContainer'>
              <span>good</span>
              <span>bad</span>
            </div>
            <span className='createdAt'>{quiz.createdAt.seconds}</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Quiz;
```

Comment: You could do a little component that hold a single question and it's responsible for its answer button state

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution like this hope this would help you,
[Live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-smoke-vvfc67?file=/src/App.js)

Parent component

```
  function App () {
  // sample array
  const quizzes = [
    {
      question: 'What is your name?',
      answer: [
        'My name is John',
        'My name is Wan',
        'My name is Maker',
        'My name is oliver'
      ]
    },
    {
      question: 'What is your Age?',
      answer: ['19 yrs', '22 yrs', '25 yrs', '28 yrs']
    }
  ]

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      {quizzes.map((quiz, quizIndex) => (
        <div key={quizIndex}>
          <p>{quiz.question}</p>
          <Answer answers={quiz.answer} />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer Component -

```
   const Answer = ({ answers = [] }) => {
  const [btnDisable, setBtnDisable] = React.useState([
    { index: 0, disable: false }
  ])

  //   disable each btn after click
  const handleAnswer = answerIndex => {
    const newBtnDisable = [btnDisable]
    console.log(answerIndex)
    answers.map((_, i) => {
      newBtnDisable[answerIndex] = {
        index: i,
        disable: true
      }
    })
    setBtnDisable(newBtnDisable)
    console.log(answerIndex, 'index')
  }

  // set all false to in initial state
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const newBtnDisable = [btnDisable]
    answers.map((_, i) => {
      newBtnDisable[i] = { index: i, disable: false }
    })
    setBtnDisable(...newBtnDisable)
  }, [])

  return (
    <div style={{ display: 'flex', gap: '10px' }}>
      {answers.map((answer, answerIndex) => (
        <button
          key={answerIndex}
          onClick={() => handleAnswer(answerIndex)}
          disabled={btnDisable[answerIndex]?.disable || false}
        >
          {answer}
        </button>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```